# iPhone app launching tips?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I just finished my first iPhone app. It's a little game and I want to launch it for 99 cents.

So my concerns is, how long usually does an app stay on the new released list. ALso, is there any launching tips on timing etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days apps stay on the new app list for hours rather than days.  It used to be that updates gave you better visibility but but my last update caused barely a blip in sales so I don't think it is true anymore.  This will probably depend on the categories you are in though.

The goldrush is sadly over.  It used to be that merely being in the app store generated hundreds or thousands of sales.  That is definitely not true any more.  Now you need either luck or marketing.

Things you can do:

- Provide review copies to as many
  sites as you can find.  Most will
  have limited visibility but if you
  can get onto a bigger site you may
  get some sales out of it.
- Provide a free limited version.
- Build a mailing list on your website
- Pimp it everywhere.  In your sig, on your website
- Start writing the second game

Answer (score 2):

ASAP - why wait, right?  In reality, your true launch date is going to be determined by Apple anyways depending on how long it takes them to review and approve your app.

Answer (score 1):

One tip I've heard is to update reasonably often.

When you update, your app may reappear on some of the category lists as being recently added/updated. This can give you some extra visibility which might just be what gets you ahead.